# Ubuntu Permission Denied Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, celery

I get he following error running this command `/etc/init.d/celerybeat start`:

```
chown: changing ownership of `/srv/project/logs': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/run': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/var/run': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/run': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `/srv/project/logs': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of `/srv/project/logs': Operation not permitted
Starting celerybeat...
ubuntu@ip-10-239-73-129:/etc/default$ LockFailed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celerybeat.pid'
```

The user it runs under is '**celery**'.

I run this command after to create the user:

```
adduser --system --no-create-home --disabled-login --disabled-password --group celery
```

But still get the permission denied error. Why?

Comment: Did u try the commands using the 'sudo' option?

Comment: yes it works with sudo, however this runs from an init script which cannot run as root i'll add the more to the question to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add user 'celery' to the sudoers group for this u need to be root user
First you can switch user to root

```
$ su root
$ adduser <username> sudo
```

Now switch back to 'celery'

`$ su celery`

Now try and execute the commands with sudo option.

Also to add celery to be the user of that folder you can use chown to change the owner of that folder (as root user)

`$ chown -R celery:celery <foldername>`

Answer (score 0):

To change permissions and create user you need root permissions, so you should login with root or you can do from normal user with sudo command if the user exists in sudoers file.

Comment: the permission on the folder is lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root run can I add celery as a user to that folder?

Comment: By login root user you can do so, but why are you doing it because your other running services under root will effect (might be stop working) because almost sevices's PID files exist in run directory.